# django twilio for number phone confirmation returns exception in send function

Tags: django, sms, twilio, send

I got an exception when i create a sms to send

here is my functions

```
def send_sms(to_number, body):
    account_sid = settings.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID
    auth_token = settings.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN
    twilio_number = '+15005550006'
    client = TwilioRestClient(account_sid, auth_token)
    try :
        client.messages.create(to=to_number,
                           from_=twilio_number,
                           body=body)

    except Exception as e:
        print e.message
```

```
def generate_code():
    return str(random.randrange(100000, 999999))
```

```
def send_confirmation_code(request,to_number):
    verification_code = generate_code()
    send_sms(to_number, verification_code)
    request.session['verification_code'] = verification_code
    return verification_code
```

Comment: Could you tell us more about the error? What kind of exception? Traceback would be helpful

Comment: That's what i got exactly :   
HTTP Error Your request was:

POST https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/XXXXXXX/Messages.json

Twilio returned the following information:

The requested resource /2010-04-01/Accounts/XXXXXXX/Messages.json was not found

More information may be available here:

https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/20404

Comment: Can you check that your Account SID is correct. That is the usual reason for a 404 response.

Comment: Thank you  @philnash,the error was in the SID